# Configuring React Router SubRoutes with React-Semantic-UI CardGroups

Tags: react-router, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I have researched this for a while, and followed documentation from the following places:

[This issue on github](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/142) led me to the [semantic-ui-react documentation on Augmentation](https://react.semantic-ui.com/introduction#augmentation),

and the react-router documentation on [setting up route config with sub-routes](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/route-config).

My route configuration seems to work, but it is unclear where to specifically implement the component augmentation.

I have tried `<Card.Group items={items} as={Link} to={items.map((item,i)=>(item.href))} />`, as well as trying to put the `as={Link}` in the props itself, and have faced a bunch of errors and eventually recursive failure leading to the dreaded `Maximum call stack size exceeded!`

For now, I am just hard coding the paths to components with react-router. A functional approach would be more elegant, and much more react-y, and this is what I'm after!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You trying to apply augmentation to `Card.Group`, while in fact you want you want to apply it to `Card`.

So correct usage for the subcomponent API is:

```
<Card.Group>
  <Card as={Link} to='/foo' />
  <Card as={Link} to='/bar' />
</Card.Group>
```

Correct usage for the shorthand API is:

```
const items = [
  { as: Link, content: 'Foo', to: '/foo' }, 
  { as: Link, content: 'Bar', to: '/bar' },
]

<Card.Group items={items} />
```

Comment: is there a way to define set up 'active' link?

Comment: @user990993 `import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'` like this?

Comment: @VladyVeselinov, yes that's it